# Upload functionality in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

I have a Visualforce page to upload the files to content and another Visualforce page with the  list of items that got uploaded and list of items to upload the page.  Now I need to add upload functionality against second page, i.e items to upload page.

I have added column to upload file against each item.  Any one done this?  Please help me with sample code

Comment: where you want  to upload? are these attachments?

Comment: uploading the file to content

Comment: Updated with screenshot

Answer (score 12):

The best way (not easy for all) to do this use JS Remoting (Javascript remoting). It prevents from hitting Salesforce governor limit. But you should be aware that you cannot upload file which exceed the limit for object. If you are not familiar with JS remoting view these [examples](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) first before proceed.

Ex: to use js remoting:

```
// Javascript function called on button click to upload
    function uploadToSalesforce(data) {
      Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MultiUploadHandler.uploadAttachment}', 
            fileName, contentOfFile, recordForWhichUploading,
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    status = 'Upload Successful' + result;
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    status = 'Upload Error'+;
                } else {
                    status = 'Upload Error';
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
```

`MultiuploadHandler` is the name of class and `uploadAttachment` is static method (JS remoting can work with static methods only and can return String) . This function passes 3 parameters (for method in apex code) + `function to show status`.

Method in apex code this is for attachment you can change it for content document with little effort:

```
@RemoteAction
public static String uploadAttachment(String filename, String fileData, String record) {
    String user = UserInfo.getUserID();
    if(fileData==null)
        return String.valueOf('Invalid file data.');
    String base64 = fileData.substring(file.indexOf(',')+1);
    Blob actualdata = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);
    if(actualdata.size()<=0)
        return String.valueOf('File size cannot be greater then 10MB.');
    Attachment att = new Attachment(ParentId=record, Body=actualdata);
    att.Name = filename;
    insert(att);
    return String.valueOf('Upload Successful!');
}
```

This example upload a attachment in orgnisation for selected record. Try to implement with documents.

Comment: this attaches the doc as a attachment to a sobject and does not attach to content, I believe the user wants to upload the file to content in salesforce.

Comment: @rao I provided approach and some possible implementation I hope this should be helpful.

Comment: Yes I do understand that he can re-modify the code, I have up voted your answer already:).

Comment: @rao Thanks! I think `JS remoting` is a nice way to do this.

Comment: @reddev How are you getting the data in `contentOfFile` param? Are you using the file Reader API on the client?

Comment: @theGreatDanton Yes, File Reader aPI is used here.

Comment: @reddev: Thanks! I had a similar req, but I have to make it work on IE8 and unfortunately there's no fileReader API available.. Still not sure how to achive this in IE8!!

Comment: @theGreatDanton Well I believe there must be workaround for this and I have done this a long time ago but no idea now. Let me know if you find some approach.